# On GCP, how to grant access to a service account in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a compute instance in project `project-b`, and a separate project `project-a`. The instance in `project-b` needs to access `project-a` using a `project-a` service account.

Answer (score 0):

In `project-a`:

- Create the service account. Suppose its name is `project-a-service-account@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.
- Grant the service account very specific, limited roles
- Create and download a key for the service account. Name it `key.json`.

In `project-b`:

- Create a compute instance
- SSH to the instance. Type all the commands that follow into this compute instance SSH shell.
- Upload key file `key.json` to the instance. If you are using the Google Cloud Console SSH window, you can do this using **Upload** in the gear icon menu in the upper right.
- Activate the service account:

  ```
  gcloud auth activate-service-account project-a-service-account@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file key.json
  ```
- Reinitialize:

  ```
  gcloud init
  ```

  - The `gcloud init` command will offer to re-initialize the current configuration, or create a new one. It might be nice to create a new one, but it's up to you.
  - Choose account `project-a-service-account@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Now, this instance in `project-b` can act as the service account in `project-a`. For example, if the service account has `compute.instances.create` permission, you can create an instance in `project-a`:

```
gcloud compute instances create new-instance --project project-a
```

Administrators of `project-a` can revoke this access by revoking the keys for service account `project-a-service-account@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Google has a [super fast-talking demo showing this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSnzoW4RlaQ&app=desktop).

Comment: This is a good answer, but there is an easier (and preferred) method when using Compute instances. Add the Compute Engine Default Service account in Project B to Project-A IAM with the appropriate roles. Now, the compute instance can access Project A and Project B. Your method removes access to Project B which can break some software running on the VM that still needs rights in Project B.